# Associated fibered space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quotient-space

I am doing research for a university project which consists of studying quotients in algebraic geometry. In some notes concerning principal bundles that given a representation of the structure group $G\rightarrow Gl(V)$ we can construct an associated fibered space as the categorical quotient $(P\times V)/G$. Do you know any reference for a rigorous construction of the latter quotient?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a link to the notes you are using. For example, in the usual construction the quotient is taken in the sense of the quotient space of a group action, i.e. the space of orbits with the quotient topology.

Comment: to show the representability of this functor, you will need fppf descent of affine schemes at some point - you probably assume that $G$ is affine.

Comment: Yeah, I am assuming that $G$ is affine. I am studying the following notes of Sorger, https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/38/005/38005695.pdf